# jquery menu animation close/open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I am trying to achieve animation on open and close but no animation on switching between menus.

Switching between menus = no do not animate

Opening and closing menu = animate (slide up if opening / slide down if closing)

I have all the above - **except** animating on close. Does anyone have any suggestions that could get me out of this hole please!

(To close the menu click 2 times on the *First* or *Second* menu link, once to open and once to close)

Here is my **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9b58Lesd/3/)**

My jQuery

```
$('.pack__button--each').each(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this);

  $(".pack__button", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.stickers__content').is(':visible')) {
      var $div = $(".stickers__content", $dropdown);
      $div.toggle(); 
      $(".stickers__content").not($div).hide();
      return false;
    } else {
      var $div = $(".stickers__content", $dropdown);
      $div.animate({
                height: "toggle",
                opacity: "toggle"
      }, "fast"); 
      $(".stickers__content").not($div).hide();
      return false;
    }    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var clicked;
$('.pack__button--each').each(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this);
  $(".pack__button", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.stickers__content').is(':visible')) {
      var $div = $(".stickers__content", $dropdown);
      if(clicked != $('.pack__button').index(this)) {
        $div.toggle(); 
      } else {
        $div.slideToggle(); 
      }
      $(".stickers__content").not($div).hide();
      clicked = $('.pack__button').index(this);
      return false;
    } else {
      var $div = $(".stickers__content", $dropdown);
      $div.animate({
                height: "toggle",
                opacity: "toggle"
      }, "fast"); 
      $(".stickers__content").not($div).hide();
      clicked = $('.pack__button').index(this);
      return false;
    }    
  });
});
```

I am counting which menu item you have clicked and saving it as the clicked variable. When you click a menu item again it checks to see if was the last item clicked or not and runs either toggle or slideToggle.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation fraudulent.eel! Great solution thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without jQuery's animate, using only CSS (using jQuery only to toggle the class): **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9b58Lesd/6/)**

**CSS:**

```
.stickers__content {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 60px;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 125px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      overflow-x: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      transition:.2s;
      transition-property:transform, opacity;
      transform:scaleY(0);
      transform-origin:bottom center;
      opacity:0;
    }
    .stickers__content.open{
      transform:scaleY(1);
      opacity:1;
    }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.pack__button--each').each(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this);

  $(".pack__button", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      var content=$(this).parent().find('.stickers__content');
    content.toggleClass('open');
    $('.stickers__content').not(content).removeClass('open')
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @AminJafari unfortunately this doesn't quite work, it's opening both menus at the same time with each click when I try in your Fiddle

Comment: Cool :) that isn't a solution still though, that's doing what I was trying to avoid. When clicking between menus it isn't good to animate them, because it looks bad. it isn't smooth. I am trying to toggle them simply on/off when switching between menus. Just like mine does now. And only animate them (slide up/down) when closing all menus. Mine works just as I wanted except when closing all menus it doesn't animate...